# Как сделать целочисленными переменные в скрипте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть небольшой скрипт (плагин). Суть его в том, что он помогает анимировать css свойство clip. Сам скрипт оперирует переменными типа float, следовательно в свойстве css значения считаются с точкой. Как отредактировать скрипт, чтобы он работал с целочисленными переменными и при этом работал?)

```
(function($){
$.fx.step.clip = function(fx){
    var elem = fx.elem,
        $elem = $(elem);
    if(fx.start === 'rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px)' || fx.start === 0) {
        fx.start = "rect(" + parseFloat(elem.scrollTop) + ", " + parseFloat(elem.scrollWidth) + ", "+ parseFloat(elem.scrollHeight) + ", " + parseFloat(elem.scrollLeft) + ')';
    } else {
        fx.start = $elem.css('clip'); // .replace(/,/g, " ");
    }
    var calcRect = function(pos){
        var arr = [],
            rect = fx[pos].slice(5).split(' ');

        for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
            arr.push(parseFloat(rect[i]));
        }
        return arr;
    };
    var sa = calcRect('start'),
        ea = calcRect('end');
    var perc = parseFloat(fx.pos).toFixed(4);
    elem.style.clip = 'rect(' +
    parseFloat( ( perc * (ea[0] - sa[0]) ) + sa[0] ) + fx.unit + ', ' +
    parseFloat( ( perc * (ea[1] - sa[1]) ) + sa[1] ) + fx.unit + ', ' +
    parseFloat( ( perc * (ea[2] - sa[2]) ) + sa[2] ) + fx.unit + ', ' +
    parseFloat( ( perc * (ea[3] - sa[3]) ) + sa[3] ) + fx.unit + ')';
};}(jQuery));
```

Comment: А где объявлено поле `fx.unit`?

Comment: Хм, действительно, объявления нет, но скрипт не мой, я поэтому и спрашиваю, как сделать, чтобы и работало, и целочисленные значения были)

Comment: Тогда такой нескромный вопрос: а вы в JavaScript разбираетесь? По поводу вопроса: попробуйте `parseFloat()` заменить на `Math.floor()`.